# Setting up JDK environment variables for Eclipse and Command line

Tags: eclipse, path, windows-8, environment-variables, java

I had Java working with Eclipse but I had to set up up Javac on the command line. I set the environment variables shown below but it doesn't work. Eclipse has now also stopped working.

[image: Environment Variables]

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I went a bit crazy and uninstalled/reinstalled loads of different jdk's. Finally one installed completely when I saved it directly to my C drive. I updated my environment variables for eclipse and for my command prompt and voila! Java is now working! I guess the problems with the space between Program Files will haunt me forever so I shouldn't save anything there anymore.